# PID tuning without transfer function

Tags: pid-controller

I want to develop a general PID not for any specific appilications. What algoritham can be used to to so? ie If I dont have a specific plant model what algorithams can be used to tune a PID so that it will fit for different systems (temperature, pressure, flow, level etc..
)

Answer (score 2):

PID controller are not bounded to any specific application, you can use them for what ever you want. 
If you don't have an analytical model for your system you can use an experimental method like [Ziegler-Nichols](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegler%E2%80%93Nichols_method), which is based on the step response, to adjust the controller gain.

Comment: (+1 for the brief answer) Ziegler-Nichols is quite aggressive on the plant though.

Answer (score 2):

If the system can be approximated with a delay plus a first order lag (in particular it's stable) you can use relay or Ziegler-Nichols methods for tuning, provided the disruptions that causes are not an issue.

You have to make sure that the sample times are fast enough and algorithm has enough adjustment range to handle different time constants.. perhaps fractions of a second to about an hour. That means some kind of adaptive behaviour in filtering of the derivative term, for example. You might want to look at what industrial process control makers such as Foxboro are offering (and to think about product liability insurance).